# List all files in (sub)directories in Azure

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am developing an azure function using Java. I need to iterate all the files in the following folder

```
aDirectory/aSubdirectoryWithManyFiles/
```

There are many files in that path,:

```
aDirectory/aSubdirectoryWithManyFiles/file1
aDirectory/aSubdirectoryWithManyFiles/file2
aDirectory/aSubdirectoryWithManyFiles/file3
aDirectory/aSubdirectoryWithManyFiles/file4
aDirectory/aSubdirectoryWithManyFiles/file5
```

so I wrote the following code in order to get them all:

```
// myCloudBlobContainer is a CloudBlobContainer
// I expected to get all files thanks to the next row
Iterable<ListBlobItem> blobs = myCloudBlobContainer.listBlobs();
// The only blob found in the container is the directory itself
for (ListBlobItem blob : blobs) {
    //log the current blob URI
    if (blob instanceof CloudBlob) {  // this never happens
        CloudBlob cloudBlob = (CloudBlob) blob;
        //make nice things with every found file
    }
}
```

The only blob iterated in the `for` is the directory, noone of the expected files. so in logs i get only the following URI:

```
https://blablablabla.blob.core.windows.net/aDirectory/aSubdirectoryWithManyFiles/
```

What should I do in order to access every file?

And in case I would have more than one subdirectory, as in the following example?

```
aDirectory/aSubdirectoryWithManyFiles/files(1-5)
aDirectory/anotherSubdirectoryWithManyFiles/files(6-10)
```

Thanks in advance

---

Edit

In order to make methods testable, the project uses wrappers and interfaces instead of directly using directly a CloudBlobContainer; basically, the CloudBlobContainer is given by `CloudBlobClient.getContainerReference("containername")`

After the answer to this question, I changed teh code to the following
so I used listBlobs with parameters `myCloudBlobContainer.listBlobs("aDirectory", true)` and I wrote the following code in order to get them all:

```
// myCloudBlobClient is a CloudBlobClient
CloudBlobContainer myCloudBlobContainer = myCloudBlobClient.getContainerReference("containername")
// I expected to get all files thanks to the next row
Iterable<ListBlobItem> blobs = myCloudBlobContainer.listBlobs("aDirectory", true); // HERE THE CHANGE
// No blob found this time
for (ListBlobItem blob : blobs) { // NEVER IN THE FOR
    //log the current blob URI
    if (blob instanceof CloudBlob) {
        CloudBlob cloudBlob = (CloudBlob) blob;
        //make nice things with every found file
    }
}
```

But this time, it doesn't go at all in the `for`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I must say that the previous answer made me to waste time; the problem was in the fact that only one `for` is not enough to find files in folders. The first `for` finds the folders and subfolders, plus (maybe, i didn't check) files that are in the "root" (let's call it like that).

Having the folders, for each of them we have to cast as CloudBlobDirectory in order to see and iterate all contained files with another `for`.

Here the solution that works for me:

```
// myCloudBlobClient is a CloudBlobClient
CloudBlobContainer myCloudBlobContainer = myCloudBlobClient.getContainerReference("containername")
// I expected to get all files thanks to the next row
Iterable<ListBlobItem> blobs = myCloudBlobContainer.listBlobs();
// only directories here, another for needed to scan files
for (ListBlobItem blob : blobs) {
    if (blob instanceof CloudBlobDirectory) {
        CloudBlobDirectory directory = (CloudBlobDirectory)blob;
        //next is in try/catch
        Iterable<ListBlobItem> fileBlobs = directory.listBlobs();
        for (ListBlobItem fileBlob : fileBlobs) {
            if (fileBlob instanceof CloudBlob) {
            CloudBlob cloudBlob = (CloudBlob) fileBlob;
            //make nice things with every found file
            }
        }
    } // else: may be we found a cloudBlob in root?
}
```

This helped me to find the right way:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1cfdc91f-e588-4839-a878-9650339a0a06/list-all-blobs-in-c?forum=windowsazuredata

Comment: I'm surprised that it's so complicated in Azure Storage. Isn't there a simpler way, like in GCS, where passing a folder prefix will work?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following override of [`listBlobs`](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/storage/blob/CloudBlobContainer.html#listBlobs-java.lang.String-boolean-https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/storage/blob/CloudBlobContainer.html#listBlobs-java.lang.String-boolean-) method:

```
listBlobs(String prefix, boolean useFlatBlobListing)
```

So your code would be:

```
Iterable<ListBlobItem> blobs = myCloudBlobContainer.listBlobs("aDirectory", true);
```

This will list all blobs inside "aDirectory" virtual folder in your blob container.

Comment: You can use method suggested by Gaurav but I would suggest to use listBlobsSegmented(String prefix). This method will help to avoid result limitation returned from blob storage.

Comment: @Harish...`listBlobs` method handles continuation token internally while you would need to handle continuation token in your code when using `listBlobsSegmented`. My preference is also to use this method over listBlobs. In this particular scenario, I would recommend using https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/storage/blob/CloudBlobContainer.html#listBlobsSegmented-java.lang.String-boolean-java.util.EnumSet-java.lang.Integer-com.microsoft.azure.storage.ResultContinuation-com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.BlobRequestOptions-com.microsoft.azure.storage.OperationContext-

Comment: If I uderstand fine, you both agee on `listBlobsSegmented`, right?

Comment: Is “dir” the name of your subdirectory?

Comment: the `container.listBlobs("aDirectory", true)` also sees no file
--- sorry Gaurav, i deleted my comment because I couldn't edit, before noticing that you wrote something.
`aDirectory` is the directory containing the subdirectories with files

Comment: Can you edit your question (rather update it) and include the latest code you're using? Please include the complete code (including how you're creating container instance). Thanks!

Comment: i did my best but there is inheritance and interfaces... the microsoft classes are wrapped in order to make them mockable (testable)